# Piwik not showing exact ip address

Tags: matomo

I am running Piwik for users in a LAN subnet of 192.168.x.x . All visitors' IP address is logged as `192.168.0.0` instead of an exact IP address.

[image: Piwik User Log]

How can I get Piwik to track the exact IP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Piwik privacy setting. Go to Settins -> System -> Privacy. You have the options to mask IPs or collect full IPs.

More Info: https://piwik.org/docs/privacy/#step-1-automatically-anonymize-visitor-ips